# How to retrieve rows from two SQL tables

Tags: sql

Let's say we have two tables as follows:

- Table A: [ID, CarName] with one row `(1, 'Fiat')`
- Table B: [ID, FirstName] with one row `(1, 'Super Man')`

My question is: what kind of query that I can run in order to return rows from the tables A and B while there is no connection between them?

The returned rows will be:

```
#1 (1,'Fiat')
#2 (1,'Super Man')
```

Thanks

Comment: Google Union all and see if that helps

Comment: My point is that there is no connection between the tables, and in the productions system I have two big tables with different columns that could be given a new name which matches both columns. For example tableA(print copy scan) tableB(Credit paypal coupon), so in the returned rows this column could be called Action

Comment: LJ01 thanks a lot, Union all did the job

Answer (score 0):

Works if both of the tables have the same number of columns:

```
select
*
from table1
union all
select 
*
from table2
;
```

If the number of columns in the table is different, you need to explicitly call missing columns in the table with fewer columns as NULL (select A, B, null from table 1;)

But it would probably be better if you get the tables to have a common key to join them on.